# Videos for finding the area under curve using integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request

Can anybody point me in the direction of some good videos for finding areas under curves using integrals? Currently studying for a calc 1 final, have found good videos on khan academy and youtube-patrickjmt for using riemann sums, finding areas between curves, surface areas of shapes, and volume of rotated shapes, but nothing for finding areas under curves using integrals

Comment: Area under curve using integral... Shouldn't this simply be integrating the function which expresses the curve and get your answer?

Comment: whoops yea just got that

Comment: Khan academy has videos about finding areas under curves.

Answer (score 1):

The videos I think are best is youtube channel: profrobbob

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3bxriE3XbM

Answer (score 1):

If you are crunched for time and really quickly want to see what you know and what you don't, try this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=di_bzYD0Mkg